# How to store a scriptblock in a variable

Tags: powershell

I can run a command on a Hyper-V host which gets information from all running VMs, but I can't get it to work if I put the scriptblock in a variable.

This works, and returns the COMPUTERNAME for all running VMs:

```
$(Get-VM | Where-Object State -Eq 'Running') | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Command -VMName $_.Name -ScriptBlock {"$env:COMPUTERNAME"} -Credential $cred; '' }
```

But this doesn't:

```
$script="$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$(Get-VM | Where-Object State -Eq 'Running') | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Command -VMName $_.Name -ScriptBlock {$script} -Credential $cred; '' }
```

I've also tried:

```
$script=[ScriptBlock]::create("$env:COMPUTERNAME")
and
{"$script"}
{"$($script)"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try with `$script={"$env:COMPUTERNAME" } ` and then `-ScriptBlock $script`?

Comment: Yay, that worked! If you make it an answer and I'll mark it so, as you were first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first failing example, the string literal expression `"$env:COMPUTERNAME"` is being evaluated on your host machine *before* any code has a chance to run on the VM - the same as any other string literal expression you assign to a variable.

In the second example, the string literal expression is evaluated when you pass it to `[scriptblock]::Create` - so the scriptblock's source code ends up becoming `{<nameOfHostComputer>}`, which is also not what you want.

Instead of using `[scriptblock]::Create`, use `{...}` to create a scriptblock literal - placing the string expression inside it will prevent its evaluation until the scriptblock is passed to `Invoke-Command`:

```
$script = {"$env:COMPUTERNAME"}
Get-VM | Where-Object State -Eq 'Running' | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Command -VMName $_.Name -ScriptBlock $script -Credential $cred; '' }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but in the first 2 examples I don't understand why it didn't return my host name?

Comment: @FrinkTheBrave Because `$script` is a local variable, it doesn't exist on the remote VM - if you wanted to reference a variable from the calling scope, you should have done `... -ScriptBlock {$using:script}`